# How to select specific element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html syntax

```
<ul>
<li class="heading">link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li class="heading">link</li>    
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li class="heading">link</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the first .heading element that comes after a normal li element that i click.I tried using the .closest() function but i didn't manage to get it right.With jQuery

Comment: that was not correct, 'first .heading element that comes after a normal li element that i click.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `click` handler do:

```
$(this).nextAll('.heading:first');
```

[`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) retrieves all the siblings after the current element that match the selector, so use use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to only target the first.

`nextAll` should not be confused with [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next), which only considers the next element (and will only return it if it matches the given selector).

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) did not work as it examines only the ancestors of the current element, where-as we want to retrieve the siblings.

You can see a JS Fiddle of this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/5e3gz/1/

Comment: Oh, I was doing the example while you did the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/5e3gz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the "adjacent sibling" selector, which is the plus sign:

```
$('.heading+li')
```

This picks all`li` elements that are immediately after an element with `class='heading'`.

Note, this is standard CSS, so the above selector will also work in your stylesheets (supported in all browsers except IE6), like so:

```
.heading+li { .... }
```

See also http://quirksmode.org/css/selector_adjacent.html for a description of how this selector works.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new. I saw this in some css styling and wondered what this was for. Now i know!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('li.heading:first'); //This selects the one you want
});
```

Check this for more help:
http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: `next` only considers the very next element, unlike `nextAll` which considers all of them.